# XCode 7.1 Simulator - 6s iPhone model behaving differently than all others

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Strange behavior on the simulator.

View Controller has a text field.  When selecting the text field, keyboard appears and the view shifts up so that the user can access the button at the bottom of the screen.  Press outside the text field, and the keyboard dismisses and view shifts back down.  Pretty basic stuff.

Recently, when I run the app on the iPhone 6s simulator, selecting the textfield makes the view shift down, and the keyboard does not appear.  Also, pressing outside the field makes the view shift down even further.  It used to work fine.  This just recently started, and I don't remember making any code changes that would cause the issue.

The funny thing is that this only happens when running the 6s simulator.  4s, 5, 5s, 6, 6 Plus, and 6S Plus all work fine.  Also, it works fine when running on an actual 6s device.  Just the 6s simulator is quirky.

Anyone else face similar problems?  Any idea how to fix this?  Here's my code, just in case.  But I'd be surprised if this were a coding issue.  Thanks!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse


let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var verificationCode : String = String()

class VerificationEntry: UIViewController {

    var keyboardInt = 0

    @IBOutlet var buttonToBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var textfieldToSubmit: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var titleToBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet var verify: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        defaults.setObject("Coding Explorer", forKey: "userNameKey")

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        self.deviceSize()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        let verInt = defaults.valueForKey("VerInt") as! Int

        if verInt < 1 {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Thank You", message: "A verification code will be emailed to you, pending approval.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            defaults.setInteger(1, forKey: "VerInt")
        }
    }



    @IBAction func submitVerification(sender: AnyObject) {

        verificationCode = verify.text!
        let userCode = defaults.stringForKey("userCode")
        var parseCode : String = String()


        do {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"UserNumber = %@", userCode!)
            let query = PFQuery(className: "OffYearUsers", predicate: predicate)
            let scoreArray = try query.findObjects()
            parseCode = scoreArray[0]["AccessCode"] as! String
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }

        if verificationCode == parseCode {
            defaults.setValue(parseCode, forKey: "accessCode")
            performSegueWithIdentifier("verifyToMain", sender: nil)
            defaults.setInteger(0, forKey: "ThankYou")
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {

        if keyboardInt < 1 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= 140
            keyboardInt++
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += 140
        keyboardInt = 0
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func deviceSize() {
        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            switch UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height {
            case 960:
                buttonToBottom.constant = 40
                textfieldToSubmit.constant = 75
                titleToBottom.constant = 340
            case 1136:
                buttonToBottom.constant = 100
                textfieldToSubmit.constant = 90
                titleToBottom.constant = 425
            default:
                print("unknown")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first reset you simulator and toggle the keyboard
hardware-keyboard-toggle software keyboard works for me when no keyboard is display

Comment: Great!  That worked.  I had both "Uses the same layout as OSX" selected, as well as "Connect Hardware Keyboard" under the simulator's Hardware menu.  Deselecting the latter resolved the issue.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing is correct behavior when a hardware keyboard is attached to the device (both real devices with a BT keyboard and in the sim when the menu item is enabled).  The reason you're seeing this behavior in the 6s and not other devices is likely because your settings are different in that device than in the others.  Hit cmd-k to toggle the onscreen keyboard (analogous to double-tapping the eject button on a bluetooth keyboard attached to a real device).